# How to check valid group seperators are present in the given number?

Tags: java, validation, numbers, number-formatting

How to validate number contains only valid group separators.

**Valid group separator:**
12,132
123,123

**Invalid group separator:**
123,45

Answer (score 1):

Split on the group separator character, and then check that the first string in the result has length 3 or less, and all remaining strings have length 3.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testit("12,132");
    testit("123,123");
    testit("123,45");
  }

  private static void testit(String data){
    System.out.println(data + " "+checkSeparator(data));
  }

  public static boolean checkSeparator(String data) {
    if (data.length() == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    String[] split = data.split(",");
    if (split[0].length() > 3) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
      if (split[i].length() != 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without doing complex things, you can just `split` from `'` and check the length.

Eg: let's say you got 3 element by `split` by `'`. Then length of `0`th and `1`st element length should be `3` and `2`nd element should be in `length<= 3`